# unable to automatically step in to the server

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services

In my project, I am trying to connect my project with my created Web Service by using the below code:

```
 web reference -->  my web service
```

---

```
 myWebSeviceClass connection = new myWebSeviceClass();
 public SingleStack retrieveSingleStackOrder(string TableName, string[] ColumnName)
 {
  /*ERROR*/   return connection.getSingleStackOrder(TableName, ColumnName);
 }
```

I am getting the following error in the above code.

[image]

My webservice file has something as below:

```
 public GetOrder.SingleStack getSingleStackOrder(string tableName, List<string> columnNames)
 {
       //my function
 }
```

Where `GetOrder` is a Class with inner class `SingleStack`.

I searched alot before asking but cant find any luck.

Comment: Not sure what was the problem.. I left investigating more on it :)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to attach to the service. On the VS menu click on **Debug -> Attach To Process...** and then browse through the list of processes and double-click your web service. The debugger will then be able to trace and step into that service.

You should notice the red circle on the left (your break point) should turn from a red outline into a solid red circle when you have attached to the correct process. If it remains a red outline then it means the debugger is not attached.

Please read [HERE](http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-asp-net-web-services.aspx) for more information about attaching to processes (you want the segment about a third of the way down titled **Second case: Debugging deployed WS**)

Comment: I am still coding in my webservice(incomplete).. In parallel, I am checking it in my page by giving web reference(updating it). Is this the correct way of doing? and to follow your explanation should I make the webservice as a application(.exe) ?

Comment: No, you should leave your web service as it is but you will probably see it appear as WebDev - 12345 where 12345 is the port for the web service. When you Start Debug it will launch both projects but only attach to the web site, you then need to go back into VS and follow my instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Has the application been built in debug mode? Release mode can prevent this from happening.

Comment: still no effect.. same problem exists.